# Why is creating listeners notorious for producing memory leaks in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

This article on memory leaks emphasizes that having superfluous event listeners leads to memory leaks in the Google Closure javascript library.

http://www.googleclosure.com/avoid-memory-leaks-with-goog-disposable/

Why event listeners in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library stores your handlers internally, the handlers will be kept there unless you explicitly remove them. There is no way for the library to know whenever you are not using some instance of a class anymore.